# How to constrain a layer to be a probability matrix?

Tags: tensorflow

I recently read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2080.pdf) which deals with noisy labels in convolutional neural networks.

They model label noise by a probability transition matrix which forms a simple 
constrained linear layer after the softmax output.

So as an example we may have a 3-by-3 probability transition matrix (3 classes):

[Example probability transition matrix. The sum of each column has to be 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W9B7.jpg)

This matrix Q is basically trained in the same way as the rest of the network via backpropagation. But it needs to be constrained to be a probability matrix. Quote from the paper:

> After taking a gradient step with the Q and the model
>   weights, we project Q back to the subspace of probability matrices because it represents conditional probabilities.

Now I am wondering what is the best way to implement such a layer in tensorflow.
I have some ideas but i'm not sure what could work or is best procedure.

1) Hard code the constraint in the model before any training is done, something like:

```
    # ... build conv model without Q
    [...]
    # shape of y_conv (output CNN) assumed to be a [3,1] vector
    y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(y_conv, 0)
    # add linear layer representing Q, no bias
    W_Q = weight_variable([3, 3])
    # add constraint: columns are valid probability distribution
    W_Q = tf.nn.softmax(W_Q, 0)
    # output of model:
    Q_out = tf.matmul(W_Q, y_conv)
    # now compute loss, gradients and start training
```

2) Compute and apply gradients to the whole model (Q included), then apply constraint

```
    train_op = ...
    constraint_op = tf.assign(W_Q, tf.nn.softmax(W_Q,0))
    sess = tf.session()
    # compute and apply gradients in form of a train_op
    sess.run(train_op)
    sess.run(constraint_op)
```

I think the second approach is more related to the paper quote, but I am not sure to what extend external assignments confuse training.

Or maybe my ideas are bananas. I hope you can give me some advice!

Comment: "Best" is likely problem dependent, but I've had some luck with your approach 1 (i.e. normalize within the model). Projecting afterwords means gradients are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will go with 1) as well and report my results. But this may still take a while...